# empty a specific element of a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to set an element at a specific position of a vector to null, so can do it as the following:

```
vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr> vec1;// filled somehow
vec1[i] = nullptr;// some specific position i
```

ps. I want to keep the entry that is nulled, which acts like a place holder, so I think maybe `vec[i] = 0` will do?

Comment: Do you just want to set the ith element's *value* to zero, or do you actually want to *remove* the element from the vector and make the vector shorter?

Comment: Is "empty" the same as "null pointer"? You've got a vector holding pointers; do you want a hole in the vector (no pointer) or a null pointer (no hole in the vector, but the pointer at position `i` doesn't point to a DOM node) ?

Comment: @Kerrek: Good question, it is an ambiguously asked question. Maybe he/she is coming from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be `erase()` will help, e.g.

```
vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i);
```

When you iterate through next, that entry will not be there...

Now that we know what you want to do, something like this ought to work..

```
vector<boost::optional<IXMLDOMNodePtr> > vec1;
// populate
// to erase
vec1[i] = boost::none; // now effectively null.
```

This is without knowing what this `IXMLDOMNodePtr` is (if it is as the name implies a pointer), then simply setting it to `0` ought to work.

```
vec1[i] = 0;
```

NOTE: If you dynamically allocated this object, setting it to `0` does not clear up the memory as setting something to `null` does in Java - in C++ you have to explicitly clean it up first, i.e.

```
delete vec1[i];
vec1[i] = 0;
```

Comment: this depends if the OP wants to actually set a value to 0 or remove it altogether.

Comment: i think i want to keep the entry which acts as a place holder

Comment: @daiyue: Please edit this into your original question.

Comment: thx for help, yes, IXMLDOMNodePtr is a smart pointer for IXMLDOMNode in msxml, and it should automatically manage referencing and dereferencing?

Comment: I don't know; if it is indeed a smart pointer then it ought to manage what it points to - you need to confirm the semantics. In this case, setting `0` will not work (this will only work if it's a raw pointer). You'll have to assign a default constructed value to it - something like: `vec1[i] = IXMLDOMNodePtr();`

Comment: out of curiosity, why assigning 0 to a smart pointer dont work here?

Comment: it depends on whether the pointer supports it - which I don't know. So safe to assume not(?)

Answer (score 3):

For removal of the element (if that's what you mean by `NULL`) you can use [`vector::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

```
vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i);
```

Or else, create a dummy object of `IXMLDOMNodePtr`, which is considered a NULL according to your coding standard and set that object:

```
const IXMLDOMNodePtr ixNULL;  // this dummy is specially created as NULL
vec1[i] = ixNULL;
// ...
if(vec1[j] == ixNULL)
 //...
```

For that you need to overload `IXMLDOMNodePtr::operator ==`.

Comment: +1 only answer that actually answers the question.

Comment: thx for help, I think I only need to create a dummy IXMLDomNodePtr, and assign it to vec[i], that i is the position of element that I want to set it null, that the dummy acts as a place holder?

Comment: @daiyue, you should also make sure that you assign the dummy elements special values (generally `0`); which will make it a worthy `NULL`. Yes, your `vec[i]` will be **replaced** by the `ixNULL`.

Comment: hi, i wonder how to set 0 to an IXMLDOMNodePtr dummy object.

Comment: since vec1[i] and ixNULL are all IXMLDOMNodePtr, so do i have to overload IXMLDOMNodePtr::operator ==.

Comment: @diayue, whatever are the members of `IXMLDOMNodePtr`; set them all to `0`; if there are other members like `vector` etc. keep them empty. Now you have to overload `IXMLDOMNodePtr::operator ==` for because, you need to compare by values. You can search on internet how typically this operator is overloaded for more info.

Answer (score 0):

No. A vector is contiguous by design. That means that a vector with `.size()==5` has elements `[0]` to `[4]`.

You may want a `std::map<int, IXMLDOMNodePtr>`:

```
std::map<int, IXMLDOMNodePtr> vec1 = foo();
vec1.erase(i);
```

Comment: can you be more specific about using std::map, i also want to keep the length of the original vector, its like empty position in between elements of the vector.

Comment: no need for a map (okay it's cheaper), but erase will work with vector too...

Comment: @Nim: Well, that depends on the meaning you assign to the index. If I remove element 2 from a map that held elements 0-4, I'd have 0,1,3,4 afterwards. If I remove element 2 from a vector that held elements 0-4, I'd end up with elements now numbered 0-3.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vec1.resize(whatever_size_you_need);` and it will expand the vector and default each element to 0. Then you can use `[]` as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vec1.erase((vec1.begin()+i);` to erase the i-th element of the vector. After that vec1.size() is reduced by 1, so if you have to write a cycle that erases some elements of the vector, a good practice is to use a *backwards* cycle ;)

Answer (score -1):

no you can't. you need to initialize the vector to have element

```
vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr> vec1(size, NULL);
```

or push back null elements

```
vec1.push_back(null);
```